# find all occurencies and put them into pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I want to analyze the string word by word.
Eg. I have string:

**Hose clip 8-12 mm W4 9 mm edge SST left right**

and on this I wanted to apply this matcher to extract only few values from that description

```
def matcher(x):
    for i in attributes:
        if i.lower() in x.lower():
            return i
    else:
        return np.nan
```

Hence I created

```
attributes =['left','right']
```

and called it like

```
df['Colours'] = df['pre_descr'].apply(matcher)
```

I thought it will give me all occurencies, but is stops after finding the first find.
So I get only

***'left'***

Then I thought I would split the string by ' ' and store this list into pandas column like this

```
a = 0
for i in df['pre_descr']:
    df.at[a, 'pre_descr_list']= i.split(' ')
    a+=1
```

and iterate over the values and store them in there is they are in the attributes list
but!

1. This gives me error
   ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
2. But I see the list:

***['Hose', 'clip', '8-12', 'mm', 'W4', '9', 'mm', 'edge', 'SST', 'left', 'right']***

Please, how would you solve it? I think I have it overcomplicated and it should be easier... but I dont know how to even specify it...
Maybe the first thing = to store the values in the column as list is not even needed?
Thanks!

Comment: You are using `return` which will only return once in a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that I need to know: Why you want this list? This list you be used for what? This may clarify the intended solution.

But, let's answer your question.

The following code must resolve your problem:

```
attributes = ['left', 'right']

df['pre_descr'].apply(lambda x: [word for word in x.lower().split(" ") if word in attributes])
```

Comment: OMG! this is pure magic. I have to learn more about lambda! Thanks tons!

Comment: Hi, by any chance, can you explain me how you constructed it? The lambda makes my head turn.... I just cant grasp it..

Comment: Lambda means that the "x" values will iterave over each value inside the "pre_descr" column. The first step will be apply lower to 'x'; followed by 'split', in wich I split the sentence in the empty spaces, after that it iterate over the sentence splitted word by word; after that, I verify if the word is in attributes list, if yes, the word is keeped.